# Should I include the @ symbol with the username when the social icon is shown as well?

Tags: social-media, username

Assume the following clickable social links at the footer of a website:

```
Find us at:
[F] @username
[I] @username
[Y] @username
```

Where `[F]` = Facebook icon, `[I]` = Instagram etc.

My question is, is it necessary to include the `@` symbol before the username? Or is it nowadays obvious enough due to the icons shows at the left so the `@` is redundant?

**Edit**: The reason I am asking is that I want to provide the most succinct version of that thing. In addition, I want to be including that section, as is, at the bottom of a printed leaflet of the client.

Comment: Not obvious. Is there a problem including @ ?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: Edited to add more context. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Necessary?** - I don't think it's necessary to put it, but the reason many people add a "`@`" tag before their **username** is that while the "`@`" tag refers to a person/organization, most social media uses the tag "`@`" for their users' usernames.

[image]
*(Which one is the **username**? The one on the left or the one on the right?)*

Also, if you are including it on a **printed** leaflet, having a "`@`" tag will help the audience know that it is a username.

If you think that it is redundant, you can do how others do for their social media links on their websites.

[image: Fiddle.Digital Website]
*(Screengrab from [Fiddle.Digital](https://fiddle.digital/) website) - A great example of social media links on footer*

Comment: In a similar vein, if you have one of the new gTLDs for your domain like fiddle.digital, it makes sense to add a www. or https:// in the printed link to let your audience know it's a URL and not just some weird way to spell your name